# Get row & column indices of found value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I get the row and column indices of the cell containing a value I'm looking for?

Here's an example of two sheets, "Grave" and "Data_grave":

[image: Grave sheet] [image: Data_grave sheet]

My code, below, should...

- First, get a specific value in sheet "Grave" (in example value is - "Win").
- Find the number of the row & column with this value in sheet "Data_grave".
- Finally, it should write some data ("wow") near the found value "Win" (from column+1).

However, I receive an error message at line 17 (the line following my search loops):

> Can't convert 4,4 to (class)

How do I solve that?

```js
function myFind() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), rowNum = [], collNum = [];
  var findData = ss.getSheetByName('Grave').getRange("A2").getValue();
  var searchData = ss.getSheetByName('Data_grave').getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=1, iLen=findData.length; i<iLen; i++) {  
    for(var j=0, jLen=searchData.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      for(var k=0, kLen=searchData[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        var find = findData;
        if(find == searchData[j][k]) {
          rowNum.push([j+1]);
          collNum.push([k+2]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ss.getSheetByName('Data_grave').getRange(rowNum,collNum).setValue("wow");
}
```

Comment: `rowNum` and `collNum` are now `array`s, so you cannot use `array`s in `getRange()` method. You need to use numbers only.

Comment: okay.. but how to get number of row and column? I mean, can i convert array into numbers?

Comment: are you expecting more than one result? if not, then don't `push()` the value in an array, simply save it in a variable. If yes, it's ok to store the results in an array, but you need to loop over the array again, so you can put "some data" near **each** "Win" column.

Comment: When you've "found" the cell you're searching for, instead of `push()`, you simply want to use `var rowNum = j+1; var colNum = k+2;`. You could also use a boolean `found` as an additional exit condition for all your loops, to stop searching upon success.

Comment: Thank you Adelin and Mogsdad !! Del push(), and now its works  well :)

Comment: Please, don't change your question. It's encouraged to add information to it, but you should not change the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adelin commented: the error message is indicating that you are not using `.getRange(rowNum,collNum)` properly. [That method expects two numbers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column), but you're providing it two arrays.

When you've "found" the cell you're searching for, instead of `push()` (which treats `rowNum` and `colNum` as arrays), you simply want to use:

```
var rowNum = j+1;
var colNum = k+2;
```

You could also use a boolean `found` as an additional exit condition for all your loops, to stop searching upon success.

```js
function myFind() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), rowNum = [], collNum = [];
  var findData = ss.getSheetByName('Grave').getRange("A2").getValue();
  var searchData = ss.getSheetByName('Data_grave').getDataRange().getValues();

  var found = false;
  for(var i=1, iLen=findData.length; i<iLen && !found; i++) {  
    for(var j=0, jLen=searchData.length; j<jLen && !found; j++) {
      for(var k=0, kLen=searchData[0].length; k<kLen && !found; k++) {
        var find = findData;
        if(find == searchData[j][k]) {
          var rowNum = j+1;
          var collNum = k+2;
          found = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ss.getSheetByName('Data_grave').getRange(rowNum,collNum).setValue("wow");
}
```